# Getting error - local variable referenced before being initialized

Tags: c

I have written a simple function which reads in a pointer to an array. It looks at the elements of the array and compares adjacent values for equality. If they are equal it adds their value to "sum"

I am getting a runtime error telling me "local "sum" was referenced before being initialized." I don't understand this because sum is definitely initialized in my function. See code snipet.

```
int arrRead (char *Pinput){

    int sum, a, b = 0;

    while (*Pinput){
        a = *Pinput;
        ++Pinput;
        b = *Pinput;
        if(a == b)
            sum += a;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `sum` is not initialized before you start adding to it.  Initialization is when you assign it an initial value.  You are not giving it an initial value, so it starts with garbage.

Comment: You don’t set `sum` to 0 before you use it.  You would need `int sum = 0, a = 0, b = 0;` to zero initialize all three variables.

Comment: Where is `sum` *definitely initialized* in that function?

Comment: Where is `sum` *definitely initialized* in that function?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value ?

Comment: Your compiler complains about a variable being used without initialization. This is not a runtime error. This is a compile time error/warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> int sum, a, b = 0;
> ```

here only `b` is initialized with `0`.

`sum` and `a` are uninitialized.

You need to write:

```
int sum = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
```

Or, each variable on its own line:

```
int sum = 0;
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
```

---

Even if in your function technically only `sum` needs to be initialized for the algorithm to work, it is a very good practice to initialize all the variables upon declaration.

---

Another good suggestion by @melpomene is to narrow the scope of the variables. For instance `a` and `b` are used only in the `while` loop:

```
int sum = 0;

while (*Pinput){
    int a = *Pinput;
    ++Pinput;
    int b = *Pinput;
    if(a == b)
        sum += a;
}
return sum;
```

Comment: Better yet: `int sum = 0, a, b;` Best: `int sum = 0; while (*Pinput) { int a = *Pinput++; int b = *Pinput;`

Comment: @melpomene I wouldn't consider anything that uses the comma operator unnecessarily to be in the "better yet" category, but I guess that comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons That's not the comma operator.

Comment: @melpomene Perhaps I misused the terminology.  What would the proper term be for the use of the comma in that instance?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Good question. The C standard doesn't mention a name; the grammar simply specifies that a declarator list consists of one or more declarators separated by `,`.

Comment: @Melpomene thanks for suggestion. But wouldn't limiting the scope of a and b in the manner you suggest, result in them being declared anew for each loop iteration?

Comment: @TestEngineer11 Not really. "Declaring" is a compile-time thing. It does nothing at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You’re not initializing `sum` with

```
int sum, a, b = 0;
```

Only `b` is being initialized.  You need to add an initializer for `sum` as well.

```
int sum=0, a=0, b = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator `+=` adds the right side value to the left side value, and then stores the sum back into the left side value.

If `sum` is uninitialized, the operation `sum += X` invokes undefined behavior; the result depends on the previous value of `sum`.